# Use databases with javascript, jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, jquery-mobile

I am starting in programming with html5 javascript and jquery mobile for mobiles. And i would know what is the best database to use. It is good to use SQL Lite?

Thanks in advance and kindest regards,

Comment: Your choice of database has nothing to do with html or jquery  When asking a question on SO you have to provide a code problem that can be solved by others.

Answer (score -2):

You can try Google Firebase. It can be done with JavaScript programming / or JQuery.